# my simple loss function cause NAN

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, nan, loss-function

I have write a customer loss for myself, but after several steps, the loss became nan, my code is

```
def my_loss(label_batch, logits_batch, alpha=1.3, beta=0.5):
    softmax_logits_batch = tf.nn.softmax(logits_batch, axis=-1)

    indices_not_0 = tf.where(tf.not_equal(label_batch, 0))  # not-zero indices
    indices_0 = tf.where(tf.equal(label_batch, 0))  # zero indices

    predict_not_0 = tf.gather_nd(softmax_logits_batch, indices_not_0)
    predict_0 = tf.gather_nd(softmax_logits_batch, indices_0)
    avg_p_not_0 = tf.reduce_mean(predict_not_0, axis=0)
    avg_p_0 = tf.reduce_mean(predict_0, axis=0)

    euclidean_distance = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(avg_p_0 - avg_p_not_0)))
    max_value = tf.maximum(alpha - euclidean_distance, 0)
    return max_value
```

Some basic ideas behind are:

1. My loss is for semantic segmentation which has only **2 categories**.
2. The shape of label_batch is **(?, H, W)**, all the value in it are 0 or 1. The shape of logits_batch is **(?, H, W, 2)** the value of logits_batch is the **logits of the FCN (without Softmax)**.
3. I want to find **all** the logits values (**predict_0** or **predict_not_0**) whose label value is 0 or 1 respectively by **indices_0** or **indices_not_0**.
4. The shape of both predict_not_0 and predict_0 should be **(?, 2)**
5. Calculate the average value for predict_not_0 and predict_0 respectively (which represents the central point coordinates of Euclidean space for category 0 and category 1). The shape of them should be **(2,)**
6. calculate the Euclidean distance between two central point coordinates, and it should larger than a certain **alpha** value (alpha = 1.3 for example)

Now, the problem is after several steps, the loss value become nan.

the output of the code is (I used a very small learning rate parameter)

```
Epoch[0],step[1],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.486435.
Epoch[0],step[2],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.485756.
Epoch[0],step[3],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.485614.
Epoch[0],step[4],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.485649.
Epoch[0],step[5],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.485185.
Epoch[0],step[6],train batch loss = 2.87279,train acc = 0.485292.
Epoch[0],step[7],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.485222.
Epoch[0],step[8],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.484989.
Epoch[0],step[9],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.48406.
Epoch[0],step[10],train batch loss = 2.8728,train acc = 0.483306.
Epoch[0],step[11],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.483426.
Epoch[0],step[12],train batch loss = 2.8728,train acc = 0.482954.
Epoch[0],step[13],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.482535.
Epoch[0],step[14],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.482225.
Epoch[0],step[15],train batch loss = 2.87279,train acc = 0.482005.
Epoch[0],step[16],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.48182.
Epoch[0],step[17],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.48169.
Epoch[0],step[18],train batch loss = 2.8728,train acc = 0.481279.
Epoch[0],step[19],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.480878.
Epoch[0],step[20],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.480607.
Epoch[0],step[21],train batch loss = 2.87278,train acc = 0.480186.
Epoch[0],step[22],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.479925.
Epoch[0],step[23],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.479617.
Epoch[0],step[24],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.479378.
Epoch[0],step[25],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.479496.
Epoch[0],step[26],train batch loss = 2.87281,train acc = 0.479354.
Epoch[0],step[27],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.479262.
Epoch[0],step[28],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.479308.
Epoch[0],step[29],train batch loss = 2.87282,train acc = 0.479182.
Epoch[0],step[30],train batch loss = 2.22282,train acc = 0.478985.
Epoch[0],step[31],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.494112.
Epoch[0],step[32],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.508811.
Epoch[0],step[33],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.523289.
Epoch[0],step[34],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.536233.
Epoch[0],step[35],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.548851.
Epoch[0],step[36],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.561351.
Epoch[0],step[37],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.573149.
Epoch[0],step[38],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.584382.
Epoch[0],step[39],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.595006.
Epoch[0],step[40],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.605065.
Epoch[0],step[41],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.614475.
Epoch[0],step[42],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.623371.
Epoch[0],step[43],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.632092.
Epoch[0],step[44],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.640199.
Epoch[0],step[45],train batch loss = nan,train acc = 0.647391.
```

**I used exactly the same code before, except the loss function is tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits() and everything works, so I suppose there is something wrong in my new loss function.**

I have a guess, maybe some batch data only have one category's label (only 0 or 1), so one of **predict_not_0 and predict_0** will have no data therefore, but I don't know how to code to validate whether there has data in **predict_not_0 and predict_0**

can somebody help me find where the problem is and how can I improve my loss function to avoid nan?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably due to the use of `tf.sqrt`, which has the bad property of having an exploding gradient near 0. Therefore, you are progressively hitting more numerical instabilities as you converge.

The solution is to get rid of `tf.sqrt`. You could minimize the squared euclidean distance for example.

Another potentiel source of error is `tf.reduce_mean`, which could return NaN when operated on an empty list. You need to figure out what you want your loss to be when that happens.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I change "tf.sqrt" to "tf.square" but the problem still exists, still from step 31. (I used the same random seed)

Comment: How can I implement "if there exist items in predict_not_0 then calculate the average value of predict_not_0, else give predict_not_0 a certain Tensor value"?

Comment: both 'tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(avg_p_0 - avg_p_not_0)))', 'tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(avg_p_0 - avg_p_not_0))' and 'tf.square(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(avg_p_0 - avg_p_not_0)))' don't work

Answer (score 0):

nan is caused by `0.0/0.0`, `log(0.0)` or some other computations in many programming language because of the floating point number computation, usually in very big or small number(treated as Infinity or zero because of accuracy).

`tf.nn.softmax` is not safe enough while training, try some other functions instead, like `tf.log_softmax`, `tf.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` and so on.

Comment: How can I implement "if there exist items in predict_not_0 then calculate  the average value of predict_not_0, else give predict_not_0 a Tensor of [0,1]"?? That is I want to avoid predict_not_0 to become None in each iteration.